# Injecting global javascript variable into a test in angular 4

Tags: angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a global javascript variable defined in a standalone js file, loaded in index.html as `<script type="text/javascript" src="./config/config.js"></script>`

```
var testConfig = {
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:3000'
};
```

And it's referenced in a service as

```
declare let testConfig: any;
```

There're reasons for doing it this way, instead of using the Environment files. Mostly because our CI process injects urls **after** ng build.

That's all working fine when I run the application with ng serve. What I'm struggling with is to get past "testConfig is not defined" error when running the jasmine tests.
Adding config.js into karma.conf.js has no effect.

karma.conf.js

```
 files: [
  { pattern: './src/config/config.js', watched: false},
  { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
 ]
```

I can't see config.js being loaded at all in the browser console though. Wonder if that's the mixture of javascript and typescript that karma can't deal with properly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: In production config.js is obviously loaded as a separate script. In tests it is likely bundled and possibly runs in strict mode. This will result in `var testConfig =` being local. It should be `window.testConfig =` or so.

Comment: Good point. Doesn't help though. `window.testConfig = {
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:3000'
};` gives me the same error

Comment: same story with window.top.testConfig = ...

Comment: actually I can't see config.js being loaded or attempted to load at all. I will update my question.